# Why it is showing two apk files when running the app on a device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created an app ,for showing the users current location in the startup and another activity for enter a destination,i have used Maps activity for displaying current location,and a intent is passed to another activity when a button is clicked.The problem is it is showing two apk files in the device one for maps activity and another for second activity and when i create a signed apk,the maps activity was not showing nothing ?How can i solve this issue??

Comment: Android doesn't normally show you apk files, rather it shows you launcher activities, and there can be more than one in a given apk. Your maps activity trouble might be a missing/misconfigured proguard rule or possibly a failure to switch to a release maps api key.

Comment: maps activity is working properly when running  the app using android stdio,but when i install signed apk of the same ..It is not working? any solution plz?

Comment: As already mentioned, check the proguard rules and that you are using a release api key.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. Have a look at the manifest and check if you have multiple rows in the whole manifest containing the

```
"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

In case yes: remove the ones that are not related to the main activity.

The correct template, that is ONLY for the main activity, is the following:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
<!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```